# FDD or SCD deployment using VS 2017

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

How do I package `.net core` application as '`a framework-dependent deployment (FDD)`' or '`a self-contained deployment (SCD)`' using Visual Studio 2017 (IDE) ? I am aware on how this can be done through dotnet CLI / command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this feature is not available at the moment. I created a feature request at [suggestions](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/18989395-integrated-fdd-and-scd-visual-studio-ide-2017).

Answer (score 4):

See [Visual Studio and Self Containing Deployments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42797956/visual-studio-and-self-containing-deployments/42817192#42817192)

Setting the `<RuntimeIdentifier>XXX</RuntimeIdentifier>` property in your .csproj makes it self-contained.  Not setting `<RuntimeIdentifier>` makes it framework-dependent.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I was looking at an integrated solution within VS 2017 itself to achieve what otherwise done through modifying csproj or dotnet CLI.

Comment: In the answer I linked to, it says `Unfortunately, this feature (picking a runtime during publish) didn't make it into the VS 2017 RTM release. We plan on adding it in a future release.`

Comment: Anyone get this working with Core 2.0??  I can't get it to copy the framework files with the deployment....

Comment: Can you share your project?  Make sure you are setting `<RuntimeIdentifier>` in your project, or passing in `-r XXX` when publishing.  Note that just building doesn't copy the framework files to the output directory.  You need to `publish` the project.

Comment: Is this valid for ASP.Net Core targeting the full framework? My csproj contains only `<TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>` (no `RuntimeIdentifier` element), but I get all DLLs in the publish folder...

Comment: No, there is no concept of "self-contained" applications on the full framework.  All the DLLs in your publish folder are assemblies outside of the full .NET Framework, like the ASP.Net Core assemblies, and some "facade" System assemblies that allow netstandard to work on net461.